# Discord.py trying to overwrite JSON file

Tags: python, json, discord.py

I am trying to overwrite what I have stored in a JSON file from WIP to complete. I am unsure on how to call a specified part of the file I want to change and my current attempt just rewrote the whole thing

Example:

{"132323232680": {"title": "Kokou", "status": "Work in Progress"}}

becomes

{"138231684456775680": {"status": "Complete"}})

Sorry if everything I said is incoherent I'm new and not very familiar with either JSON or Python and coding as a whole. Thanks in advance.

Edited the code slightly since posting.

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

users = {}


@bot.event
async def on_ready():

    global users
    try:
        with open('users.json') as f:
            amounts = json.load(f)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Could not load amounts.json")
        users = {}



@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def register(ctx, *, title):

    id = str(ctx.message.author.id)
    if id not in users:
        wip = "Work in Progress"
        users[id] = {"Title": title, "status": wip}
        await ctx.send(title + " is now " + wip)
        _save()
    else:
        await ctx.send("Finish the one you started!")


@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def complete(ctx):
    id = str(ctx.message.author.id)
    if id not in users:
        await ctx.send("try again")
    else:
        wip = "Complete"
        users[id]['status'] = wip
        await ctx.send(" is now " + wip)
        _save()


def _save():
    with open('users.json', 'w+') as f:
        json.dump(users, f)


@bot.command()
async def save():
    _save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should update only the specific key of the dictionary, you are overwriting the whole structure right now:

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

users = {}


@bot.event
async def on_ready():

    global users
    try:
        with open('users.json') as f:
            amounts = json.load(f)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Could not load amounts.json")
        users = {}



@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def register(ctx, *, title):

    id = str(ctx.message.author.id)
    if id not in users:
        wip = "Work in Progress"
        users[id] = {"Title": title, "status": wip}
        await ctx.send(title + " is now " + wip)
        _save()
    else:
        await ctx.send("Finish the one you started!")


@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def complete(ctx):

    id = str(ctx.message.author.id)
    if id not in users:
        wip = "Complete"
        users[id]['status'] = wip
        await ctx.send( " is now " + wip)
        _save()
    else:
        await ctx.send("Try again")


def _save():
    with open('users.json', 'w+') as f:
        json.dump(users, f)


@bot.command()
async def save():
    _save()
```

The key change being `users[id]['status'] = wip`

Comment: First off thanks for the reply, I actually have tried this however I get discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: KeyError: '138231684456775680' also just realized  IF ID NOT IN is in the wrong order. Thanks for steering me in the right direction.